# Is it correct and natural to say "the load is picking up in Boston" meaning the pick-up point is in Boston?

Tags: present-continuous, present-simple

Would you tell me if it's correct and natural to say *the load is picking up in Boston* meaning the pick-up point is in Boston? For example:

> The load is picking up in Boston at 5PM tomorrow and is delivering in New-York on Saturday.

If it's not natural would be more natural to say the following way?

> The load picks up in Boston at 5PM tomorrow and delivers in New-York on Saturday.

Comment: Both are natural. Do you have a problem with either one?

Comment: No I don't. Do the mean the same?

Comment: No - you need the passive voice here. *The load **is being picked up** in Boston at 5PM*. Although noting the (Pennsylvanian) dialectal form [***His car needs washed***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24163/) I suppose your "active" version might occur in some dialects (but I'd say it's definitely "sub-standard" to mainstream Anglophones, so it should be avoided).

Comment: The load isn't doing the picking up. The load *is being picked up*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that it depends upon with whom you are speaking.   If you are speaking with someone in the trucking / freight industry, where that term is frequently used, then it is fine as it is.  It's a well-established and often used phrase that, should you change it up, you risk being misunderstood (and the load quite possibly not being picked up).

Speaking to someone unfamiliar with trucking might find the statement a bit awkward and at best generate a quizzical look.    I don't believe that it's incorrect, though.

Comment: What you say is true. Industry insiders often have their own lingo.

Comment: Airport workers often say e.g. 'your plane is boarding at 10:30', and a shop worker might say 'these hot cakes are selling very well'.